# How can we build an ionic project in Ubuntu 18.04, which is developed and built in windows environment?

Tags: ionic-framework, ubuntu-18.04, node-sass, windows64

i am trying to build an ionic project in ubuntu 18.04. but I am getting an error like it cannot build in ubuntu environment.

I have rebuild node-sass folder as well. After that I am getting error as gulf.file cannot find.

[here is the error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xt9x.png)

Comment: Have you tried running any of the commands the error is actually giving you?

Comment: yes Tachyon. I tried with npm rebuild command. After that when I build the project I am getting error like, gulf.file is not found.

Answer (score 0):

copy files from your old project folder except node_module 
then paste them in the new path 
run 
***if cordova  not installed***

```
npm install -g cordova
```

then run

```
npm install -g ionic
npm install
```

if any error shows
run

```
npm audit fix
```